# Adding total number of days between 2 dates from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I would like to do is calculate the number of days between 2 dates that are in an array.

Example:

```
StartDate = new Array("08 Feb 1954", "16 Sep 1955", "25 Nov 1955",
                      "19 Oct 1956", "13 Jun 1958", "08 Aug 1958", 
                      "05 Sep 1958", "02 Jan 1959", "19 Jun 1959", 
                      "07 Aug 1959", "03 Nov 1959", "11 Dec 1959", 
                      "15 Apr 1960", "20 May 1960", "21 Oct 1960", 
                      "11 Nov 1960", "20 Dec 1960");

EndDate   = new Array("26 Aug 1955", "28 Oct 1955", "07 Sep 1956",
                      "23 Nov 1956", "25 Jul 1958", "22 Aug 1958",
                      "07 Nov 1958", "17 Apr 1959", "31 Jul 1959",
                      "02 Oct 1959", "04 Dec 1959", "25 Dec 1959",
                      "13 May 1960", "10 Jun 1960", "04 Nov 1960",
                      "18 Nov 1960", "14 Feb 1961");

for ( var i = 0; (i < 17); i++ )
{
     numdays = date_diff_indays(StartDate[i], EndDate[i]);
     TotalDays += numdays;
}
```

How can I make the `StartDate` and `EndDate` into a multidimensional array calculation?

This is what I have for the calculations:

```
var date_diff_indays = function (date1, date2) 
dt1 = new Date(date1);
dt2 = new Date(date2);
return Math.floor((Date.UTC(dt2.getFullYear(), dt2.getMonth(), dt2.getDate()) - 
                   Date.UTC(dt1.getFullYear(), dt1.getMonth(),dt1.getDate())) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
```

How do I loop the array to get the number of days between the dates, then add the numbers together to get a total number of days?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to do the calculations for you, in this example that would be `calculateDates`. What this does is calculate the number of days between 2 dates.

Then loop thru your startDate array and call your function inside the loop.

`totalDays += days` to calculate the total

```js
var calculateDates = function(date1, date2) {
  var dt1 = new Date(date1);
  var dt2 = new Date(date2);
  return Math.floor((Date.UTC(dt2.getFullYear(), dt2.getMonth(), dt2.getDate()) - Date.UTC(dt1.getFullYear(), dt1.getMonth(), dt1.getDate())) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}

var startDate = ["10 Jan 1982", "05 Mar 1990", "28 Dec 2001"];
var endDate = ["25 Jan 1982", "06 Mar 1990", "02 Jan 2002"];

var totalDays = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < startDate.length; i++) {
  var days = calculateDates(startDate[i], endDate[i]);
  console.log("Number of days between", startDate[i], "and", endDate[i], "is", days);
  totalDays += days; 
}

console.log("Total number of days:", totalDays);
```